# Dummy variables in function definition.

Tags: functions, notation

When we use 'dummy' variables whose scope are limited to the definition, how do we treat them? Do we assume they are independent to vary freely like in a set definition, where until a constraint is applied we consider them free to vary over any set that's defined? So we can consider them to freely vary over the function's domain?

For example, if I'm given $F(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ What can I assume, are $x$ and $y$ varying over the domain, and are they independent of one-another? Are they limited to the domain or defined for all reals?

If $x$ and $y$ are constants it's probably enough to define the function if I know that $f$ is defined the same at all points in $D$ (not piece-wise) as $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ is true for all $x$,$y$ in $D$ so if we have two constants $f(a,b)$ will have the same form as $f(x,y)$.

Comment: See [Free and bound variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables): "The term "dummy variable" is also sometimes used for a bound variable (more commonly in general mathematics than in computer science)".

Comment: Can you give an example of a definition you're having trouble understanding? There aren't formal rules governing the top-level language in which we establish definitions (because before stating such rules, we'd still have to define objects to which the rules apply), but there are conventions.

Comment: @Karl If I'm given say, Let $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ I can make some assumptions, this statement is true for all $(x,y)$ in D and $x$ and $y$ are independent? What assumptions can I make?

Comment: @Karl I assume you could use the definition on two constants $x$ and $y$ too, and then I obviously would then have to understand that based on the definition of $f$ this will be true for any other numbers.

Comment: What if your function $F$ is defined by
$$F(x,y)=\left\{\begin{split}x^2+y^2&\text{ for }x^2+y^2<1\\\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}&\text{ else }\end{split}\right.\quad ?$$ What do we have to understand here whether what is true for any other numbers ?

Comment: @KurtG. you are correct, I should have added 'if $f$ is defined in the same way at all points'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a definition $f(x,y)=\dots$ is given:

- Some domain (a set of of $(x,y)$ pairs) should be given or understood/assumed from context. With no context, I'd guess that the domain for $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ is $\Bbb R^2$.
- Unless stated otherwise, the given expression is assumed to hold for all $(x,y)$ pairs in the domain. (Asking whether $x$ and $y$ are "independent" doesn't really make sense, but I think this is what you meant.)
- This means the definition can be applied to constants. That is, you can "evaluate" the function by plugging in values, as long as you know the pair you're plugging in is in the domain.
- There's no special rule for piecewise expressions, but a piecewise expression may *simplify* if you know enough about the input values to rule out some of the cases.
- It would be confusing if the author used the names of constants (that were still "in scope"/in use) as the variable names in the definition, so they should avoid that.

Comment: the idea of 'independence' is that in the set $D$ is there some relation that must be true between $x$ and $y$, in this case it depends on the domain of $f$. What happens if I introduce a parameter $f(x)=ux$ is $u$ 'in scope' in the rest of my workings?

Comment: Yeah, so your notion of "independence" is a property of the domain of the function, which the author should specify. If a parameter is used in the definition of the function, it should be introduced explicitly (as in "let $u$ be a real number"), but sometimes we have to infer this from context. There are no rules for how to end the scope of a symbol - this is a matter of understanding the author's intent. If you introduced $b$ by defining $f(x)=bx$ and then later used the letter $f$ to refer to a new function, it might be confusing (and useless) to keep referring to $b$.